# How to properly configure flutter and dart behind a proxy

Tags: flutter, dart, proxy

I'm having huge difficulties on configuring flutter (and dart) by working from a Windows 10 machine behind a corporate proxy (credentials required).
This is what I've done by following the standard flutter installation procedure:

1. installing git-> **done**. Have to launch from cmd this command for make it work:
   git config --global http.proxy http://user:pass@proxy:port
2. installing flutter sdk -> **done**. Here start the problems. Launching flutter doctor the first time needs to download the dart sdk, that fails because of the proxy. So I followed [this workaround](https://fantashit.com/flutter-behind-proxy/) and then it worked.
3. launching flutter doctor -> **fails**. When I launch that command it goes: 
   Bulding flutter tool...
   Running pub upgrade...
   and just stops there. I tried to follow [this dart troubleshooting guide](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/troubleshoot#pub-get-fails-from-behind-a-corporate-firewall) but doesn't help.
   And of course, also android studio when tries to launch pub get or pub upgrade just get stuck the same way, and I've noticed that dart.exe is going on the task manager also if I close android studio.
   Also I've set Windows system variables http_proxy and https_proxy = user:pass@proxy:port but don't help.

   The best thing I got is getting:
   Proxy failed to establish tunnel (407 Proxy Authentication Required)
   if I try to cast from cmd the set https_proxy command using different typing combinations of user:password@domain:port

I really don't know what to do next. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: I've managed to copy from another pc the whole \flutter folder with "flutter doctor" already launched, and now it's working also on this "proxy" pc.  
But...in android studio when it runs "flutter pub get" Got TLS error trying to find package whateverpackage at https://pub.flutter-io.cn.
pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 1 in 1 second...   no luck!

Comment: any answer to this problem, having the same issue

Comment: @Eular no, I ended up by doing a remote desktop session with another PC with direct Internet access...